# Sockets not working for React native and Node.js server using ws

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, react-native

I am trying to connect my backend(node.js server) to frontend (react native app) using sockets.
But the problem is the code never goes into io.on('connection', ...).
i.e. socket connection is not being established.

Any help is appreciated.

This is client-side code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
    Button,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';    


export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
        console.log("This is client side Web socket.")
        ws.onopen = () => {
            console.log("Its connected")
            ws.send('something'); // send a message
        };

    }
}
```

This is server-side code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
      console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

install npm module `socket.io-client` then try

```
  import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Button,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';



export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ws = SocketIOClient('ws://localhost:3000'); // replace localhost with ip
    ws.on('connect', function() {
      console.log("hello");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I just found the problem. It works fine for IOS but not for Android.
Could you help me out with that ?

Comment: replace localhost your ip then check .. in my Android and iOS device working fine

Comment: Changing localhost to ip worked! Thank you. Though am unable to understand why that happened!